# How to implement icons instead of links in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a primitive Delete link in front of my objects in database. It looks pretty plain and simple. I want to find a way to implement deleting via trash bin icon like in the example. 
[image]

what do I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: read about http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
link_to (image_tag('delete.png')), 'javascript:void(0)'
```

This will show a delete icon instead of link text.

If you are not handling delete with JS then **javascript:void(0)** can be replaced by the `rails_path`